# Definitive hand conditioning answer?

Tags: discussion

We get a question about hand conditioning every few months. Over and over again, we've told people to [not do it](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/8075/1780), that it's no longer necessary (if it ever was) to cripple yourself to make your hands a more effective weapon. Is there any worth in creating a definitive post with the facts, much like how Fitness SE has standard posts for [how to lose fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/how-to-lose-fat-fast-and-healthily/13256#13256) and [the myth of spot reduction of fat](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/when-fat-is-burnt-where-is-it-taken-from/6251#6251)?

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in developing a canonical question and answer, I would encourage it.

Comment: Ditto. The key is to make it clear it is intended to be a canonical answer, and to make it clear that the community can contribute to the answer at any time.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of related questions you may wish to redirect as duplicates to the proposed canonical q/a:

- [How to condition knuckles?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/how-to-condition-knuckles/)
- [How can I make my knuckles harder?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/how-can-i-make-my-knuckles-harder)
- [Rice filled bag or mung bean filled bag which one is effective for training?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/8258/rice-filled-bag-or-mung-bean-filled-bag-which-one-is-effective-for-training/)
- [Is hitting hard objects really effective in making bones harder?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/5728/is-hitting-hard-objects-really-effective-in-making-bones-harder)
- [Is it good to practise punching a wall? No place for punching bag](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/1690/is-it-good-to-practise-punching-a-wall-no-place-for-punching-bag/)
- [Arm Toughening Without Losing Sensitivity](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/arm-toughening-without-losing-sensitivity/)
- [How to make knuckles bigger like Bruce Lee's knuckles?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9183/how-to-make-knuckles-bigger-like-bruce-lees-knuckles)
- [King of Iron Palm Training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/king-of-iron-palm-training/)
- [Iron palm monster hand training](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/iron-palm-monster-hand-training)